# TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined ( even after making all the changes)

Tags: node.js, firebase, elasticsearch, firebase-realtime-database

Sorry for asking this question again, but I tried all the solutions and I keep getting this error. I am connecting the `elastic search` to my Android project. I am stuck at this, I have tried everything.

Snapshot of the error:

[image: This is the snapshot of the error]

This is my `index.js` file I have made all the changes but still getting the error.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const request = require('request-promise')

exports.indexPostsToElastic = functions.database.ref('/posts/{post_id}')
.onWrite(( change,context) => {
    let postData = change.after.val();
    let post_id = context.params.post_id;

    console.log('Indexing post:', postData);

    let elasticSearchConfig = functions.config().elasticsearch;
    let elasticSearchUrl = elasticSearchConfig.url + 'posts/post/' + post_id;
    let elasticSearchMethod = postData ? 'POST' : 'DELETE';

    let elasticSearchRequest = {
        method: elasticSearchMethod,
        url: elasticSearchUrl,
        auth:{
            username: elasticSearchConfig.username,
            password: elasticSearchConfig.password,
        },
        body: postData,
        json: true
      };

      return request(elasticSearchRequest).then(response => {
         console.log("ElasticSearch response", response);
      });
});
```

This is code of my package.json file

```
{
 "name": "functions",
 "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
 "scripts": {
 "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
 "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
 "start": "npm run shell",
 "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
 "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
 "dependencies": {
 "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
 "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0",
 "request": "^2.88.0",
 "request-promise": "^4.2.4"
 },
 "private": true
 }
```

This is the snapshot of my database

[image]

Comment: Where is java coming into picture? All I can see is a js file and a json file

Comment: I'm adding elastic search to the project, this is the code which is giving error.

Comment: @AnkitChourey you should remove java and android since they are not related

Comment: ohh got it..i'll do it

Comment: Is the database reference correct?

Comment: i did'nt get you, where should i check?

Comment: share a snapshot of your database please

Comment: sure, i have added the snapshot in the end of the question, below the json file code

Comment: solved the error thanks for all your help

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: `change.after` is undefined.  Check it before you try to call val() on it.

Comment: I was so focused on error that i was forgetting to deploying function on firebase after updating the code. I did it and it worked, Thanks for helping me again